# Slack Conversations API conversations.info "channel_not_found"

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I have a Slack bot that uses a slash command, but I first need information from the conversation.

Required Scopes for conversations.info (mine only needs im:read and mpim:read):

- channels:read  groups:read  im:read  mpim:read

```
    payload = request.form
    headers = request.headers
    trigger_id = payload['trigger_id']
    channel_id = payload['channel_id']
    user_id = payload['user_id']
    timestamp = headers['X-Slack-Request-Timestamp']

    conversation_info = slack_client.conversations_info(
        token=SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
        channel=channel_id
    )
```

This code is returning the "channel_not_found" error when I invoke the Slack Bot from within my personal DM's, am I missing something? I have both im:read and mpim:read scopes added. I even tried the tester from Slack's API page and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I have been ashed this on Slack Support, and they said, you can not see information about private channels and direct messages, which the bot is not member of. They said, privacy is over everything.

You can invite a bot into private groups with `/invite @BotName`, but you can't invite to direct messages.

You can only see information about direct conversation, if you are using a UserToken, and the token's owner is part of that DM.